# Convert pseudo-code with nested for-loops to Clojure

Tags: clojure, nested-loops, translate

I want to implement this psuedo code in Clojure:

```
   function(n)                                       
       B[0] <-- 1                                      
       for m <-- 1 to n do                           
           B[m] <-- 0                                  
           for k <-- 0 to m - 1 do                     
               B[m] <-- B[m] − binom(m+1, k) * B[k]   
           B[m] <-- B[m]/(m+1)                               
       return B[n]
```

My first thought was to do something like this:

```
(defn foo [n]
  (if (= n 0)
    (int 1)
    (for [k (range 0 (- n 1))]
      (* (binom (+ n 1) k)
         (foo k)))))
```

but now I'm stuck and I don't know how to continue. The nested loops confuse me a lot when I try to translate them to Clojure.

I'd really appreciate some help on how to write this code in Clojure, I feel a bit lost.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pseudo code uses plenty of in-place updates which makes it a bit hard to read. But essentially, the code computes a list of numbers where every number is computed from the previous numbers in the list. And then we pick one of the numbers in the list.

I would implement this algorithm like

```
(defn compute-next-B [B]
  (let [m (count B)
        m+1 (inc m)
        terms (map-indexed (fn [k Bk] (- (* Bk (binom m+1 k)))) B)]
    (conj B (/ (apply + terms) m+1))))

(defn foo [n]
  (->> [1]
       (iterate compute-next-B)
       (drop n)
       first
       last))
```

The outer loop from the pseudo code is the lazy sequence produced by `(iterate compute-next-B ...)`. The inner loop from the pseudo code is the iteration inside `(apply + terms)` on the lazy sequence `terms`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But could you please explain why you first "drop n"? How come you drop the ones you return? I don't understand... @Rulle

Comment: @kim120 My code is an implementation of an iterative algorithm. The code `(drop n)` means that we drop the results of the first `n` iterations of that algorithm, including the initial value `[1]`. The following call to `first` means that we take next result in the sequence. That result is the vector `B`. The final call to `last` means taking the last element of that vector.

Answer (score 1):

The given pseudocode computes the nth [Bernoulli number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number). It uses all the previous Bernoulli numbers to compute the result. Much like the factorial function, this lends itself to a recursive algorithm which may be implemented with `memoize` to avoid re-computation of earlier numbers:

```clj
(def factorial
  "Returns n!."
  (memoize (fn [n]
             (if (< 1 n)
               (* n (factorial (dec n)))
               1N))))

(def bernoulli
  "Returns the nth Bernoulli number."
  (memoize (fn [n]
             (if (zero? n)
               1
               (let [n!    (factorial n)
                     term  #(/ (* n! (bernoulli %))
                               (factorial %)
                               (factorial (- n % -1)))
                     terms (map term (range n))]
                 (reduce - 0 terms))))))
```

```clj
(map bernoulli (range 9)) ; => (1 -1/2 1/6 0N -1/30 0N 1/42 0N -1/30)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some algorithms are naturally imperative in nature. Don't be afraid to write imperative code if that is the easiest solution, rather than trying to "force fit" the algorithm into a functional style.

This algorithm could easily use a mutable atom to store the `B` array:

```
(defn factorial [x]
  (reduce * (range 2 (inc x))))

(defn binom [n k]
  (/ (factorial n)
    (factorial k) (factorial (- n k))))

(defn bernoulli [n]
  (let [B (atom (vec (repeat n 0)))] ; allocate B[0]..B[n-1] = zeros
    (swap! B assoc 0 1) ; B[0] = 1
    (doseq [m (range 1 (inc n))] ; 1..n
      (swap! B assoc m 0) ; B[m] = 0
      (doseq [k (range m)] ; 0..(m-1)
        (swap! B #(assoc % m  ; B[m] = ...
                    (-
                      (get % m) ; B[m]
                      (*
                        (binom (inc m) k)
                        (get % k)))))) ; B[k]
      (swap! B update m ; B[m] = B[m] ...
        #(/ % (inc m))))
    (get @B n)))

(dotest
  (dotimes [i 10]
    (spyx [i (bernoulli i)])))
```

with result

```
[i (bernoulli i)] => [0 1]
[i (bernoulli i)] => [1 -1/2]
[i (bernoulli i)] => [2 1/6]
[i (bernoulli i)] => [3 0N]
[i (bernoulli i)] => [4 -1/30]
[i (bernoulli i)] => [5 0N]
[i (bernoulli i)] => [6 1/42]
[i (bernoulli i)] => [7 0N]
[i (bernoulli i)] => [8 -1/30]
[i (bernoulli i)] => [9 0N]
```

You could also use `with-local-vars` for some algorithms, or even drop down into a (mutable) Java array.  You can see an example of that in [this mutable Java matrix example](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/v22.05.04/src/cljc/tupelo/array/mutable.cljc#L69)